# json_decode returns false if a value has leading zeros

Tags: php, json

### Description:

When parsing a JSON Payload containing integers or floats with leading 
zeros as values which haven't been escaped using double quotes, 
json_decode() returns false.

Even thought leading zeros are ( most of the times ) irrelevant for 
integers, the function should at least trim the zeros out and not fail 
the entire decoding process. JSON returned from some Java JSON 
generators come with integers containing leading zeros and not escaped 
by double quotes.

### Reproduce code:

```
<?php

$payload = <<<payload
{
  "test" : 06
}
payload;

if(!$obj = json_decode($payload)) die("Problems on JSON Parsing the json_decode() function     has returned false");

print_r($obj);
```

### Expected result:

```
stdClass Object ( [test] => 6 )
```

### Actual result:

```
Problems on JSON Parsing the json_decode() function has returned false
```

### My problem:

This isn't quite JSON as explained [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50286). I can't really control what my user sends me, and can't tell them to be so specific as to trim leading zeros.

How can I trim zeros before feeding the payload into json_decode?

Comment: This isn't a bug with PHP. That just isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Have you read the linked ticket's reply? I don't see a point in supporting broken JSON implementations. Tell your clients to use a standards-compliant JSON library and that's all.

Comment: Like @Blender said, it's not valid JSON. [You can check here to see what valid number values are](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, is there anything I can do on PHP's end to correct for the leading zeroes? Quite a few users have built legacy systems already, and I'd rather just fix it on my end.

Comment: @Reddox: There isn't a simple workaround aside from essentially writing your own JSON parser (which isn't that difficult). Using regex to replace the leading zero will match things that it shouldn't (unless the format of the JSON is fairly static).

Comment: Re: "This is documented as a bug in PHP here." Actually, if you read that page carefully, you'll see **Status: Not a bug**, and you'll see the reason why it's not below. I have removed that incorrect information from your post.

Comment: So you're asking help writing a parser for something similar to JSON. What problem are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: @ikegami That link was still useful though. It practically answers why `json_decode` doesn't handle leading zeroes.

Comment: @ikegami "This issue has already been reported here:" or something. `;)`

Comment: @ikegami, I'm exploring making a parser without using regex. Any pointers on how to get started would be helpful!

Comment: Why wouldn't your parser use regex?!

Comment: @Blender makes a valid point with how regex might replace things it shouldnt.. So thought it best to explore other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be stuck in the unfortunate position of supporting crappy users / client software.

Try this regular expression replacement. If the data payloads are large, you may need to tweak some [pcre limits](http://php.net/manual/pcre.configuration.php)

```
$sanitisedJson = preg_replace('/(?<=:)\s*0+(?=[1-9])/', '', $payload);
```

Comment: This works great with one zero! How would I handle 'n' leading zeros?

Comment: You should just need to add a plus sign: `$sanitisedJson = preg_replace('/(?<=:)\s*?0+(?=\d)/', '', $payload);`

Comment: @Reddox I've updated my answer (with some help from Jeff's comment)